# Regex to split string if it containt wordA or wordB

Tags: php, regex

Edit again to trying to make it more clear.

Wich php regex pattern will give me a match array containing always 2 values wich is the 2 part of a string splitted by the "wordA" or "wordB". 
If the string do not containt those word, simply return the string as the first array an null in the second array.

Exemple:

```
preg_match("pattern","foo wordA bar",$match), $match will contain array['foo', 'bar']
preg_match("pattern","foo wordB bar",$match), $match will contain array['foo', 'bar']
preg_match("pattern","foo bar test",$match), $match will contain array['foo bar test', null]
```

I know that $match first value is always the string so I just don't write it.

OLD question:

I need to split a one line address into part.
I can't find a way to capture street part but dont include the APP or APT word if present and if present, capture the words after it.

For exemple:

"5847A, rue Principal APP A" should match:  (5847, A, rue Principal,A)

"5847A, rue Prince Arthur APT 22" should match: (5847, A, rue Prince Arthur, 22)

"1111, Sherwood street" should match: (1111, , Sherwood street, )

I'm using PHP.

What I have so far is: `/^(\d+)(.*), (.*)(?:APP|APT)(?:\s*(.*))?$/i` wich wook with exemple 1 and 2. If I try to make the alternative (APP|APT) optionnal by adding an ? after it, then the third match include the word APP or APT...

Any idea how to exclude the optionnal and alternative APP or APT word from match?

Thank you

EDIT:

I can simplify the problem: How can I regex a string so the match return the same string minus the word APP or APT if he is present in the middle of it.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. Addresses come in many different shapes and sizes. Either set a standard format and go with it, or parse it with another mean. Using regex implies that there's a constant pattern. Which there isn't when using something as arbitrary as an address.

Comment: I can simplify the problem: How can I regex a sentence so the match return the same string minus the word APP or APT if he is present in the middle of it.

Comment: Have a look at [`str_replace()`](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove APP or APT out.

Comment: How will you do it with a php regex?

Comment: Why do you need a php regex if you can do it without it?

Comment: Because I want to learn how to resolve some problem with regex.

Comment: You learn to use the tools that are right for the job. Regex isn't that tool in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadaraUchiha pointed out, it's a bad idea to run a regex on an address since they can be in any format.

If you know you have consistent addresses, then I guess you can use the regex:

```
^([0-9]+)([A-Z])?,\s(?:(.*?)\s(?:APP|APT)\s(.*)|(.*))$
```

And the replace:

```
$1,$2,$3$5,$4
```

[Here](http://www.regex101.com/r/kC3nU2)'s how it's performing.

It's pretty similar to yours (I changed few things) and added an or (`|`) operator to address the second type of addresses without `APP` or `APT`.

If you want consistent number of matches, maybe this?

```
^([0-9]*)([A-Z]?),((?:(?!\sAPP|\sAPT).)*)(?:\sAPP|\sAPT)?(.*)$
```

[Regex101 example](http://www.regex101.com/r/mP2dG1).

Comment: That almost it but that is give me inconsistent number of match with different part in different index of the result match array.

Comment: @JfRondeau I'm not sure why you want the solution to be more complex than it already is... but it's up to you I guess... Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for the "easy" version

```
 var_dump(preg_replace ( "/ apt|app /i" , "" ,"5847A, rue Prince Arthur APT 22"  ));
```

covers it

that outputs

```
5847A, rue Prince Arthur 22
```

the harder version you would need more context like why the commas appear like they do.

the hard version

```
([0-9]*)([a-z]?),(((?!app|apt).)*)(?:app|apt)?(.*)
```

seems to work on your test cases

Comment: The comma in the result is just to display the content of the $match array.

Comment: "1111, , Sherwood street,"   is that a mistake then having 2 commas ?

Comment: No. What I mean is that the result of the regex should give me a match array containing 4 value. "1111, , Sherwood street," mean array("1111",null, "Sherwood street", null)

Comment: the second nukll being the lack of A at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$pattern = "/\bAPP|APT\b/i";
$subject = "1111, Sherwood street";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $subject);
```